# Dynamic allocation doesn't work

Tags: c++, dynamic, allocation

I'm not good at English language. But I want to be better.

I'm trying to know-more about Pointer while I have some problem.

Some lines of code:

```
main()
{    
     // Declerations
     int y = 99;
     int** p = new int*[2];


     // Set value
     // Ok
     for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
         p[i] = new int(y--);

     /* This case, it's fail
     for (int i=0; i<2; i++, p++)
         *p = new int(y--);
     */

     //Print
     for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
         cout << p[i][0] << " ";

     // release memory
     for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
         delete p[i];
     delete[] p; 

     getch();
}
```

This is my thinking about **pointer in this code block.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJaUX.png

I don't know why It doesn't work at "This case". 
Help me, I want an explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Your main function is missing a return type.

Comment: Something inside me said - "Even don't think about that..." way of coding. Read some good C++ book and program accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. 
I write on Devc++ so Main function doesn't need a 'return'. 

Is my coding style bad? . Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you modify `p` in the loop (`p++`) you loose the original pointer, so after the loop `p` will point somewhere else. All dereferencing of `p` after that loop will cause *undefined behavior*.

If you want that outcommented loop to work, without changing `p`, you have to do it using a temporary variable:

```
int** t = p;
for (int i=0; i<2; i++, t++)
    *t = new int(y--);
```

**Note:** If you run *both* allocation loops, you will have a memory leak as the pointers allocated by the first loop will be overwritten.